# Can you Explain Why this C code does not work?

Tags: c

I am learning C can you me tell why this code doesn't give any output or error

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   int fahr,celc;
   int lower,upper,step;
   lower = 0;
   upper = 100;
   step = 10;

   fahr == lower;
   while(fahr<= upper){
        celc = 5*(fahr-32)/9;
        printf("%d\t%d\n",fahr,celc);
        fahr = fahr+ step;
   }
}
```

Comment: I guess `fahr == lower;` should be `fahr = lower;`

Comment: Turn on warnings. Fix them. For *gcc* and *clang* use `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`, for example.  `fahr == lower` should produce some kind of "code has no effect" warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have any output, because of line:

`fahr == lower;`

`fahr` is not initialized. And because it's local variable, it stores some garbage value. This garbage value high probability is more than `upper`.
That's why you don't come inside loop

```
while(fahr<= upper)
{...}
```